# Trouble writing Rails Controller Test - Get it to call def update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Why is this test failing? And how can I get it to successfully test

After profiles are edited there is a method called in the controller

## controller

```
def update
   call_the_method - method works on my machine
end
```

## test

```
  test "edit should change approval status" do
    login_as(@denied_profile)
    patch :update, id: @denied_profile, profile: {ALOT OF DUMMY INFORMATION }
    assert @denied_profile.approval_status == Profile::ApprovalStatus::DENIED_EDITED
  end
```

The method isn't called after the patch request. What is the proper way of writing htis test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you saved the `approval_status` field in database in `update` action, then all you have to do is after the `patch` request, **[reload](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-reload)** the `@denied_profile` so that it can fetch the updated record from database.

```
test "edit should change approval status" do
  login_as(@denied_profile)
  patch :update, id: @denied_profile, profile: {ALOT OF DUMMY INFORMATION }
  assert @denied_profile.reload.approval_status == Profile::ApprovalStatus::DENIED_EDITED
end
```

Use `@denied_profile.reload.approval_status` instead of `@denied_profile.approval_status`

Comment: Thank you!! @Kirtki Thorat!